# How is it possible to have a non-static non-type parameter for c++ templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

C++ templates are compile-time constructs. How is it possible that, in C++20, a template function can be instantiated with a non-static object?

```
struct X {};
template<typename T, X x> auto f() {
    return x;
}

int main() {
    auto x = X{};
    f<double, x>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `x` the variable itself is *not* what becomes the template parameter. The template parameter is declared as a value, so `f<double, x>()` actually *copies* (at compile-time) `x` to form the value of the template parameter. That is, the converted expression that is the template parameter includes a *copy* by aggregate-intialization. This is the same as if you had called a function of prototype `void f(X x)`. C++ has value semantics!

When evaluating the template arguments in `foo<double, x>()`, it is not be allowed to *read* from `x`. (More correctly, `x` is of class type and "reading" doesn't make sense; what would be illegal is reading scalar subobjects—"primitives" like `int`s, `float`s, etc. in `X`'s fields.) But, in this case, there are no fields in `X`, so copying `x` to form the template argument *needs no reads of `x`*. So nothing illegal needs to happen! `foo<double, x>()` compiles successfully, because the template parameter value can be determined without doing anything non-constant. (Note in particular that forming a reference to a non-`constexpr` variable *is* allowed in a constant expression.)

It might be instructive to note that the following also compiles. Again, the important thing is that `foo<double, x>` asks for `x` to be *copied*. Here, the user-specified copy constructor doesn't actually do any reads of `x`, so the code compiles. But the default copy constructor would read from `x`, and using that constructor makes the code not compile.

```
struct X {
    int i;
    constexpr X() : i(0) { }
    constexpr X(X const&) : X() { } // (1) does not read source object!
    // if (1) is commented out, the call to foo will fail to compile
    // the compiler-generated copy constructor if (1) is commented out is effectively
    // constexpr X(X const &x) : i(x.i) { }
};

int main() {
    X x;
    foo<double, x>();
    //          ^ as a converted expressions *includes a call to the copy constructor*, and that call is indeed a constant expression!
}
```

Finally, note that `static` is only needed to *return the address of/a reference to* an object from a constant expressions. Looking at the *value* of an object does not require it to be `static`. You can even look at the address of a non-`static` object in a constant expression, as long as you don't include that address in the result.

```
consteval int g(int const *i) {
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    constexpr int j = g(&i); // allowed, i is not static, since return value j carries no trace of non-constant &i
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument has to be entirely available at compile time.

The example as stated is not usable if the type `X` has a non-static data member in it:

```cpp
struct X { 
   int  value;  // <<==== added this
};
template<typename T, X x> auto f() {
    return x;
}

int main() {
    auto x = X{};
    f<double, x>();
}
```

It is going to complain

```bash
<source>:8:17: error: the value of 'x' is not usable in a constant expression
    8 |     f<double, x>();
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
<source>:7:10: note: 'x' was not declared 'constexpr'
    7 |     auto x = X{};
      |          ^
```

To fix that you have to declare `x` as constexpr

```cpp
struct X { 
    int  value; 
};
template<typename T, X x> auto f() {
    return x;
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto x = X{3};
    f<double, x>();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/f56nb1Ped

Now imagine that this is similar to passing an integer as a template parameter.

```cpp
template< size_t N >
struct CharT {
   char data[N];
};
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that it still works if you have a _`static`_ variable in `X`.

Comment: Yep I guess I should have said "local" instead of variable

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if it's static, what matters if it's available compile-time. `x` in the code above is available compile-time due to how it's defined. You can read more on this under `constexpr` (and, for functions, `consteval`).

Comment: But it's not declared `constexpr`, so how is it available at compile-time?

Comment: @NicolBolas it has no (own or inherited) non-static member variables.

Comment: This answer needs more clarity.

Comment: @lorro: "*it has no (own or inherited) non-static member variables.*" Does that matter? If so, why?

Comment: _"You can read more on this under constexpr (and, for functions, consteval)"_ can I read more under this answer?